# Prove that $a\sqrt{\log_{a}b}=b\sqrt{\log_{b}a}$.

Tags: logarithms

To prove $a\sqrt{\log_{a}b}=b\sqrt{\log_{b}a}$.

I take $y=a\sqrt{\log_{a}b}$

$\Rightarrow y^{2}=a^{2}\log_{a}b$

$\Rightarrow \bigg(\dfrac{y}{a}\bigg)^{2}=\log_{a}b$

$\Rightarrow a^{\big(\frac{y}{a}\big)^{2}}=b$, then I don't understand how to proceed.

please some one help me. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you believe this?  If we take $a=10,b=100$ the left hand is $10\sqrt 2$ and the right hand is $100 \sqrt {.5}$

Comment: Terribly incorrect inequality. Please check the question given to you again.

Comment: It should be $a^\sqrt{\log_{a}b}=b^\sqrt{\log_{b}a}$ I presume.

Answer (score 5):

You were to prove that $\forall a,b$ $$a^2 {\log b\over \log a}=b^2{\log a\over \log b}\\\implies {a\over \log a }=\pm {b\over \log b}$$

which is **not true**.Take $a=2,b=3$

LHS$=6.64$ RHS$=6.28$